# python. re.findall and re.sub with '^'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I try to change string like s='2.3^2+3^3-√0.04*2+√4',
where 2.3^2 has to change to pow(2.3,2), 3^3 - pow(3,3), √0.04 - sqrt(0.04) and
√4 - sqrt(4).

```
s='2.3^2+3^3-√0.04*2+√4'
patt1='[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\^[0-9]+|[0-9]+\^[0-9]'
patt2='√[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|√[0-9]+'
idx1=re.findall(patt1, s)
idx2=re.findall(patt2, s)
idx11=[]
idx22=[]
for i in range(len(idx1)):
    idx11.append('pow('+idx1[i][:idx1[i].find('^')]+','+idx1[i][idx1[i].find('^')+1:]+')')

for i in range(len(idx2)):
    idx22.append('sqrt('+idx2[i][idx2[i].find('√')+1:]+')')

for i in range(len(idx11)):
    s=re.sub(idx1[i], idx11[i], s)

for i in range(len(idx22)):
    s=re.sub(idx2[i], idx22[i], s)

print(s)
```

Temp results:

`idx1=['2.3^2', '3^3']
idx2=['√0.04', '√4']
idx11=['pow(2.3,2)', 'pow(3,3)']
idx22=['sqrt(0.04)', 'sqrt(4)']`

but string result:

```
2.3^2+3^3-sqrt(0.04)*2+sqrt(4)
```

Why calculating 'idx1' is right, but re.sub don't insert this value into string ?
(sorry for my english:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using only `re.sub()`

Input string:

```
s='2.3^2+3^3-√0.04*2+√4'
```

Replacing for `pow()`

```
s = re.sub("(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\^(\d+)", "pow(\\1,\\2)", s)
```

Replacing for `sqrt()`

```
s = re.sub("√(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", "sqrt(\\1)", s)
```

Output:

```
pow(2.3,2)+pow(3,3)-sqrt(0.04)*2+sqrt(4)
```

`()` means group capture and `\\1` means first captured group from regex match. Using [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) you can get the detail explanation for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I've only got python 2.7.5 but this works for me, using `str.replace` rather than `re.sub`. Once you've gone to the effort of finding the matches and constructing their replacements, this is a simple find and replace job:

```
for i in range(len(idx11)):
    s = s.replace(idx1[i], idx11[i])

for i in range(len(idx22)):
    s = s.replace(idx2[i], idx22[i])
```

#### edit

I think you're going about this in quite a long-winded way. You can use `re.sub` in one go to make these changes:

```
s = re.sub('(\d+(\.\d+)?)\^(\d+)', r'pow(\1,\3)', s)
```

Will substitute `2.3^2+3^3` for `pow(2.3,2)+pow(3,3)` and:

```
s = re.sub('√(\d+(\.\d+)?)', r'sqrt(\1)', s)
```

Will substitute `√0.04*2+√4` to `sqrt(0.04)*2+sqrt(4)`

There's a few things going on here that are different. Firstly, `\d`, which matches a digit, the same as `[0-9]`. Secondly, the `( )` capture whatever is inside them. In the replacement, you can refer to these captured groups by the order in which they appear. In the `pow` example I'm using the first and third group that I have captured.

The prefix `r` before the replacement string means that the string is to be treated as "raw", so characters are interpreted literally. The groups are accessed by `\1`, `\2` etc. but because the backslash `\` is an escape character, I would have to escape it each time (`\\1`, `\\2`, etc.) without the `r`.